# WPF Datagrid/Listview INVERTED?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

Is Possible to get a datagrid (or listview) control inverted?
For example, usually we have a listview like this:

***Name Age Job***

John 23  eng

Now I want to invert the table:

*Label   1col*

**Name**   John

**Age**    23

**Job**    eng

Thus we can able to select the single column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google I find this fantastic solution:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/09/22/lt-howto-gt-replace-listview-columns-with-rows-lt-howto-gt.aspx

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: The link is now dead with 'Error establishing a database connection'. A mirror is available here: http://web.archive.org/web/20130613103948/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/09/22/lt-howto-gt-replace-listview-columns-with-rows-lt-howto-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Current WPF DataGrid dioes not perform this straight away...

But there are options...

**XML Way**

XML format of data can help you to achieve this.

e.g

```
        <Employees>
            <Employee>
               <FirstName>A</FirstName>
               <LastName>B</LastName>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
               <FirstName>C</FirstName>
               <LastName>D</LastName>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
               <FirstName>P</FirstName>
               <LastName>Q</LastName>
            </Employee>
        </Employees>
```

needs to be transformed using an XSLT that converts it into something like this...

```
        <Columns>
           <Column Name="FirstName">
               <Employee>A</Employee>
               <Employee>C</Employee>
               <Employee>P</Employee>
           </Column>
           <Column Name="LastName">
               <Employee>B</Employee>
               <Employee>D</Employee>
               <Employee>Q</Employee>
           </Column>
        </Columns>
```

The column headers has to be overriden by styles that hide the column header names when transformation takes place.

Also `RowHeader` has to be styled to "steal" names `/Column@Name` in the same order as they appear in the data.

**Rotate Transform Way**

Roate the data grid in 90 degreess and each cell content in 270 degrees. Dont know if Layout or Render transform gives better results...

Let me know if this guides you in correct direction.