# GridView with columns and rows swapped

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a GridView. My requirement is like -

```
Name        C1    C2    C3    C4
Age         24    25    26    27
Gender      M     F     M     F
```

I didn't get any solution. Please suggest correct solution.

Do I need to create a new UserControl for this?

Comment: What?? What is the question?

Comment: What you want is an "inverted" grid view.  Read this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646053/wpf-datagrid-listview-inverted

Comment: [check this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified)

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql.html

Or try to create a view to bind data with ur gridview .